# ReadProcessMemory entire process

Tags: c#, c++, c, windows, readprocessmemory

I'm trying to read an ENTIRE process with `ReadProcessMemory` but for some reason no matter what, trying to read at low addresses causes the function to fail.

For example, if I'm reading from a process, I can access areas of its memory without a problem. But the lower addresses of the process, like 0, can't be accessed and `ReadProcessMemory` fails on those.

Is there some privileges I need to be able to access the ENTIRE process with `ReadProcessMemory`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some memory pages are intentionally set to unreadable, especially the first page, because that detects a lot of programming errors.

You can determine if you are able to read the memory page in another process with `VirtualQueryEx`.

To determine the size of the memory page use `GetSystemInfo`.

You have to read the memory page by page.

Also, check out this article that explains why you should not use `IsBadReadPtr` instead of `VirtualQuery`: [IsBadXxxPtr should really be called CrashProgramRandomly](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060927-07/?p=29563)

Comment: Very unfortunate for performance reasons as there are thousands of pages which must be read.

Comment: @Jire you could inject a DLL in other process, and scan the memory from inside the process.